# my application closed after launching web browser process

Tags: c#, oauth

I am having issues with my application hanging up until after I close my second form. 
I am trying to do a Dropbox integration and have all working except I have a window that the user needs to enter their oauth code then click complete. but the browser doesn't appear until after I close the form window. If I insert the show dialog after the dropbox auth then the application just closes all together and launches the browser. Any tips ?

```
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        drobbox_auth.Visible = false;
        DropBoxConfiguration config = CloudStorage.GetCloudConfigurationEasy(nSupportedCloudConfigurations.DropBox) as DropBoxConfiguration;
        config.AuthorizationCallBack = new Uri("http://www.ballisticcommunications.com/thankyou.php");
        DropBoxRequestToken requestToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxRequestToken(config, "key here", "key here");
        String AuthorizationUrl = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxAuthorizationUrl(config, requestToken);
        Process.Start(AuthorizationUrl);
        DropBoxStorageProviderTools.ExchangeDropBoxRequestTokenIntoAccessToken(config, "key here", "key here", requestToken);
```

Comment: `ShowDialog` waits until the window is closed. Also, look into the `WebBrowser` control to integrate the browser into your own (accessible) form, instead of opening the `AuthorizationUrl` with the default browser. The internet is flooded with examples for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I do agree that there is a huge ton of resources out there that explain, for some reason I am just not getting Oauth2.0 at all. I am wondering if anyone out there has an actual example of connecting to a provider like box.com and uploading a file. every one I have seen thus far utilizes a different method.